# Centering a Google Map based on parsed XML Latitude and Longitude values

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, xml-parsing

This bit of Javascript parses an xml file which contains latitude and longitude co-ordinates for a start and end point. I can get the markers out on a map fine, the issue I'm having is that the map doesn't center on the points (eventually it's going to make a call to the Google Directions Service and draw a route between the two points, so would be good to have the map fit nicely around both points rather than just centering on one of the points).

At the minute the map is created using hardcoded lat and long values so I know that needs changing, but I've tried putting in 'startpoint, and 'endpoint' to no avail, the map doesn't load, so I'm guessing the way I'm doing it below is incorrect.

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

          downloadUrl("xml.php", function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var name = markers[i].getAttribute("title");
                var startpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("startlat")),
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("startlng")));
                var endpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("endlat")),
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("endlng")));
                var html = "<b>" + name;
                var icon = customIcons || {};
                var startmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: startpoint,
                    icon: icon.icon,
                    shadow: icon.shadow
                });
                bindInfoWindow(startmarker, map, infoWindow, html);
                var endmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: endpoint,
                    icon: icon.icon,
                    shadow: icon.shadow
                });
                bindInfoWindow(endmarker, map, infoWindow, html);
            }
        });

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(startpoint, endpoint),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    });
```

This is the output of the XML...

```
<markers>
     <marker title="Journey" description="Lorem Ipsum..." startlat="53.403023" startlng="-2.130801" endlat="53.414257" endlng="-2.094128"/>
</markers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generate a bounds using your startpoint and endpoint, you can fit the map to display that bounds.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
   zoom: 13,
   mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
});

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(startpoint);
bounds.extend(endpoint);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Once again geocodezip, you have come up trumps. Thank you it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`LatLng` expect's `latitude` and `longtude` of the point where you want to center your map.
And that is why below code doesn't work.

```
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(startpoint, endpoint),
```

To show the route between two point's on centre of the map. you can try finding the middle point between your start and end point.

Here is an implementation in java that calculate's middle point, more info - [Haversine_formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

```
public static void midPoint(double lat1,double lon1,double lat2,double lon2){

   double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);

   //convert to radians
   lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
   lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
   lon1 = Math.toRadians(lon1);

   double Bx = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);
   double By = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(dLon);
   double lat3 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(lat1) + Math.sin(lat2), Math.sqrt((Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) * (Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) + By * By));
   double lon3 = lon1 + Math.atan2(By, Math.cos(lat1) + Bx);

   //print out in degrees
   System.out.println(Math.toDegrees(lat3) + " " + Math.toDegrees(lon3));
}
```

**Edit:**

*Javascript implementation*

```
function middlePoint(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2){

   var dLon = toRad(lon2 - lon1);

   lat1 = toRad(lat1);
   lat2 = toRad(lat2);
   lon1 = toRad(lon1);

   var Bx = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);
   var By = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(dLon);
   var lat3 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(lat1) + Math.sin(lat2), Math.sqrt((Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) * (Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) + By * By));
   var lon3 = lon1 + Math.atan2(By, Math.cos(lat1) + Bx);

   var middlePoint = new Object();
   middlePoint.latitude=lat3;
   middlePoint.longitude=lon3;
   return middlePoint;

}
function toRad(Value) {
    return Value * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, certainly sheds light on a solution to my issue. Unfortunately I have never come into contact with Java before so your example looks completely foreign to me.

Comment: You can implement that in whatever language you are good at....You just have to use this formula ..http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula.... i am sure you can find some inplementation in javascript out their...so try for it.

Comment: In the JavaScript version, change `Math.toRad` to just `toRad`. Also have some missing `var` declarations.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Thank's man... I did that in hurry... and didn't noticed the problem.